# How to use protocol pattern in storyboard

Tags: objective-c, delegates, protocols

I have used protocol to send data between two view controllers without using storyboard.

```
ViewControllerB * viewB=[[ViewControllerA alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerB" bundle:nil];
viewB.delegate=self; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewB animated:YES];
```

How to impliment this with storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to impliment this with storyboard.

There's less need to create a protocol to communicate between two view controllers when you use a storyboard. Typically, you'll use storyboard segues to transition between view controllers. When a segue is triggered, the current view controller will get a `-prepareForSegue:sender:` message, which has the segue as its first parameter. The segue has references to both the "source" and "destination" view controllers, so you can get a reference to the new view controller (the destination) and pass it whatever data you like at that time.

If you do still want to make the current view controller the delegate of the destination and let them use whatever protocol you can dream up, you can set the new controller's delegate in `-prepareForSegue:sender:`. The rest (creating the protocol, implementing it, etc.) is exactly the same as you've always done.

Comment: Is there a way to pass data to the first view controller from second view controller other than using protocol.